# How to assign values to vector of vectors in C++ from a file?

Tags: c++

I have declared this:

```
const std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>> input;
std::string s = "";
```

I am reading a file:

```
std::ifstream file("some.txt");
```

When I do,

```
 int count = 0;
    while (std::getline(file, s))
    {
        input[count] = somefunction(s); //return value is of this function is of type: vector<uint8_t>
        count += 1;
    }
```

It shows an error saying `no operator "=" matches these operands`

Comment: Could you show us the whole error message?

Comment: If `input` is constant, how do you expect to assign to it?

Comment: @GillBates With an Uru hammer.

Comment: Note: `std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>> input;` produces a zero-by-zero array. You will want to `push_back` a `std::vector<uint8_t>` for each line you read from the file, and then `push_back` into that line-`vector` each value you read off the line.

Answer (score -1):

change your code to as below:

```
 int count = 0;
    while (std::getline(file, s))
    {
        input.push_back(somefunction(s)); //return value is of this function is of type: vector<uint8_t>
        count += 1; // not mandatory you can use size() function to get the count;
    }
```

vector can not be initialized as array (like `array[i]=7`), `vect[i]=9` **is incorrect**(if not resized  or no-memory allocation), though it can be initialized as array on declaration.
Vector is accessible like array (`cout<<vect[i]`);
Check below link for more details on initializing vector:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/initialize-a-vector-in-cpp-different-ways/

Comment: @HaeshGiri *vector can not be assigned values as array of c++ (like array[i]=7)*:  really? What if you have resized or initialized the vector with some values. Instead of providing the external link, why can't you give a small insight to the problem? and heart of the story (`const vectror`) is still not been explained.